# How to set apache2 RequestHeader only for a Location?

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy

I want to set a `RequestHeader` `X-Forwarded-Prefix`, but only apply it to specific paths.

Pseudocode:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Location /api1>
        ProxyPass https://host/api1 http://localhost:8080
        ProxyPassReverse https://host/api1 http://localhost:8080

        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix "/api1"
    </Location>

    <Location /api2>
        ProxyPass https://host/api2 http://localhost:8080
        ProxyPassReverse https://host/api2 http://localhost:8080

        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix "/api2"
    </Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Is that possible at all?

If not, how could I pass different `X-Forwarded-Prefix` values based on the redirected context path (here: /api1 and /api2)?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me, when I wanted to configure Apache2 web server to pass an original subdir prefix from forwarded host to a target host within the request header.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...

    ProxyPass /subdirName1 http://otherHost1:port1
    ProxyPassReverse /subdirName1 http://otherHost1:port1
    <Location /subdirName1 >
        RequestHeader add x-forwarded-prefix "/subdirName1"
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /subdirName2 http://otherHost2:port2
    ProxyPassReverse /subdirName2 http://otherHost2:port2
    <Location /subdirName2 >
        RequestHeader add x-forwarded-prefix "/subdirName2"
    </Location>

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I specifically needed this to let webpages load dependencies such as CSS and JS from the correct address, for example: not from `/css/...` but from `${forwardedPrefix}/css/` (where `forwardedPrefix` is set to `subdirName1`, taken from the header.

This was made possible because the request header that was received by server `otherHost1` (`port1`) contained variable `x-forwarded-prefix` with the value `/subdirName1`, so that the target service could re-construct their `/`-based URL's correspondingly.

This works for all HTTP methods, `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.